# Actionscript 3.0: Cannot get key input

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

guys. I created a little game. Nothing actually happening thought, because im not getting my keyboard input. I spend some time trying to create my own taht didnt work. Then I copy/pasted code from official actionscript 3.0 reference page, but tweaked it for my game (but I didnt touch anything related to keyboard stuff).  Also the only thing my game returns in cosnole is false

```
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

stop();

var left = false;
var right = false;
var speed = 0.3;


player.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keydF);
player.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyuF);
player.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updF);

function keydF(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
    trace("test0");
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.D) {
        trace("test1");
        left = true;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.A) {
        right = true;
    }
}

function keyuF(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
    trace("test2");
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.D) {
        left = false;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.A) {
        right = false;
    }
}

function updF(e:Event):void {
    if(left) {
        level.x -= speed;
    }

    if(right) {
        level.x += speed;
    }
    trace(left + ""); //always false :\
}
```

Comment: Try adding the listeners to the stage.

Comment: this seemed to run the method keydD and keyuF (printed out test0 and test2). Yet it didnt acces the if statements inside those methods. My output looks something like this.false
test0
test0
false
test0
false
test0
test2
false
false
false

Comment: ok, it seems like restarting the whole computer (not just flash) helped. Thanks a lot!, you should provide an answer :D

Comment: FYI for people finding this later (to give some context), when you add the listener to the player, that means that player object has to have the current focus to receive the event.  if the application itself has focus, then stage will dispatch the event regardless of the child that actually has the focus (since stage is a parent of everything).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the key input to your app, you should add the listeners to the stage :)